# Linking 64-bit NASM with MinGW-64 causes "File format not recognized" error

Tags: assembly, mingw

I am trying to assemble and link a 64-bit NASM program on Windows using MinGW-64bit with the following batch command:

```
nasm -f win64 HelloWorld.asm && "C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe" HelloWorld.obj -o HelloWorld.exe
```

But I get this error:

```
HelloWorld.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: A possible fix might be to switch to some Linux system, maybe using it thru [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). Another fix might be to install some recent [Debian](http://debian.org/) on a separate [disk partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning). Be sure to backup your important data before trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that, although I downloaded and installed MinGW-64, I still got a 32-bit version because I selected the i686 option upon installation.  I reinstalled with the "x86-64" option and it fixed the problem.