# hello.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to run assembly language(x86) in vs code. I run `nasm -f elf64  hello.asm` to create the object file and then I run `ld -o hello.exe hello.o` to make the .o file into exe file. But it says this `hello.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`. What will I do. I have set the nasm path variable at environment variables.

Comment: Are you on Windows, using a Windows linker?  You need `nasm -fwin64`, not Linux/BSD ELF object file format.

Comment: That or maybe [Linking 64-bit NASM with MinGW-64 causes "File format not recognized" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62112200) .  You definitely want `nasm -fwin64` if you're trying to make a 64-bit Windows executable, though.